# How to use .htaccess to redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have a folder structure like this:

```
apps:
   public
       test/index.php
```

Now I want the url `localhost/apps/test` to point to `localhost/apps/public/test/index.php`, how should I do it? Should I use a .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

In your apps folder, add this to the top of your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test$ /apps/public/test/index.php [L]
```

If you actually want to redirect the browser (e.g. change what's in the URL address bar), add a `R` to the square brackets: `[L,R]`

Comment: when I try this, it redirects me to localhost/public/public/test/index.php, any ideas why?

Comment: Do you have another rule that is redirecting stuff (like to remove the `/apps` part of the URL)?